# Set of probability measures with support in open $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open in the weak topology?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-topology

Fix an open set $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ and consider the following set of probability measures, where $\mathfrak{M}(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the weak topology:
$$ B = \{ P \in \mathfrak{M}(\mathbb{R}) \: : \: \text{supp}(P) \subset D \} $$
Is $B$ open in the weak topology?

The support of a probability measure on a separable metric space (like $\mathbb{R}$) is the smallest closed subset of probability 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Let $D = (-1,1)$, an open set.  Let $\mu_n$ be the probatility measure with mass $1/n$ at point $5$ and mass $(n-1)/n$ at point $0$.  Then $\mu_n$ converges to the unit-point-mass at $0$.  Although all $\mu_n$ are outside $B$, the weak limit is in $B$.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful!